# How to Securely Deploy Alpine Linux using LXC

Tags: docker, security, containers, alpine-linux, lxc

I'm new to the container world. I would like to deploy a Alpine Linux LXC container and then install Docker on Alpine but IDK anything about this OS or how to secure it once it's deployed. I'm currently using a Ubuntu LXC container with docker installed inside of it since I'm familiar with securing Ubuntu but would prefer to use Alpine in order to reduce overhead. Are there any books, documents or videos that discuss best security practices for Alpine Linux? I haven't been able to find any relevant results from Googling. Any help answering this question would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you mean with "how to secure" an alpine container deployment? The answer will always be "it depends". Security is big word that might refers to different layers. Please be more specific with your question, if you want a specific answer. Otherwise you will get a series of link like these (which I believe you don't want):
https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/security/
https://archive.fosdem.org/2018/schedule/event/containers_workload_security/attachments/slides/2563/export/events/attachments/containers_workload_security/slides/2563/Everything_you_need_to_know_about_containers_security.pdf